# WINDOWS 10, firewall file missing

Tags: windows-10, firewall

Windows 10 cannot be updated. Error message 0x800706d9. Firewall is not running and when I try to reset to defaults I get a message that there are Firewall  file(s) missing. Microsoft "trouble" scan can't detect or repair. Still using version 1511 because it's unable to update Windows 10 (dozens of updates have failed).
Performance is pathetic especially when trying to enter text for emails. Sometimes I have to wait for minutes before it will allow me to continue.

Comment: Sounds like a HDD issue.  Confirm with chkdsk.  Upgrade to 1607, mount the ISO, if that fails bite the bullet and Reset your installation.  If that fails, backup data, replace hdd and install 1607.  Activation will be automatic, product key is not required, skip that step when installing on a fresh installation

Comment: I also could not update windows 10 - kept getting 0x800706d9. The only solution appears to be re-enabling Windows Firewall, which I had disabled. No idea why disabling that prevented it from updating, but as soon as I manually re-enabled and restarted it, the windows updates started downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Try running [sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) to see if it restores any missing system files. After the scan finishes reboot the system and try updating.

Comment: I did as you suggested and interestingly, the result showed no files missing. However, when I re-booted, the Firewall was functioning!!??? Maybe I will now be able to get Windows 10 updates. Thanks.